# O Careers está funcionando pra você?

Tags: debate, careers

Já uso o Careers há algum tempo, e até já me candidatei para algumas vagas com trabalho remoto (porque estou planejando trabalhar em outro país num futuro próximo). Não obtive resultados. Só tenho 1 visita no meu perfil público (gerada por mim) e 30 aparições na listagem de resultados - logo, não estou sendo notado.

É realmente isso, ou o site é irrelevante, quando comparado a outros sites de carreira? Se alguém puder me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado, será de grande ajuda.

Aqui está a URL do meu perfil, para quem quiser me estapear com as coisas que estou fazendo errado (obrigado!)

[**http://careers.stackoverflow.com/tiagocesar**](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/tiagocesar)

*[Postado também no SOEN Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223623/is-careers-working-for-you)*

Comment: A princípio achei q vc estava reportando algum problema técnico. Para mim não, tive duas visitas no dia que criei e uma no dia seguinte, mas eu também nunca dei muita bola para ele.

Comment: Acho que isso é off-topic aqui no nosso meta...

Comment: @bfavaretto o meta ficou para discussões gerais em português, na falta de comunidades específicas para outros temas. Postei no Meta do SOEN e até os moderadores do Careers responderam e não consideraram off-topic

Comment: Lá acho que não é off-topic mesmo. Mas aqui é para discussões sobre o SO em português, o Careers estaria fora do escopo.

Comment: Lembrando que o "metão" é tanto do SO quanto da rede Stack Exchange em geral (mas isso está em processo de separação, o SO em breve terá um meta "normal" como o nosso).

Answer (score 4):

Olha, acredito que existam vários fatores. Sou [membro do Caarers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/aaccioly) há muito tempo e até hoje só recebi uma oferta de emprego (como *telecommuter*) e quatro visualizações do meu perfil. Tive muito mais ofertas (nacionais e internacionais) através de outros sites populares. Acredito que isso ocorra por uma combinação de fatores:

- Meu primeiro ponto é que o Careers continua sendo uma site muito exclusivo. Tenha visto grandes oportunidades nas áreas de *Data Science*, *Information Retrieval* e para especialistas técnicos trabalhando com tecnologia de ponta (NoSQL, Cloud Computing, Computação Resiliente, etc). Eu não ousaria redigir um currículo como fiz no Careers em nenhum outro lugar.
- Esses nichos estão começando aqui no Brasil, tenho impressão que até as empresas nacionais que anunciam por lá estão buscando "importar" talentos através do site.
- Até por questões de conformidade com o processo de imigração, vagas para relocação são geralmente limitadas para especialistas. O nível de competição (excelentes candidatos / vaga) no SOE é bem alto e com certeza entram em jogo fatores como proximidade (como bem disse o OnoSendai).
- Finalmente acredito que o Careers, principalmente aqui no Brasil, ainda não atingiu massa crítica.

Há três anos eu [sugeri no meta do SOen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91557/158926) que o perfil no Stack Overflow fosse linkado ao currículo do usuário no Careers. Hoje finalmente recebi [uma resposta de um funcionário](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229088/158926) da Stack Exchange. Eles estão [trabalhando na renovação da página de perfil](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226177/the-profile-page-is-getting-a-makeover), a nova versão vai contar com um link para o CV no Careers. Isso deve ajudar a gerar tráfego (pelo menos no meu caso, meu perfil sempre teve muito mais visualizações e é bem rankeado no Google).

Comment: Valeu, cara. Pra mim de certa forma foi um balde de água fria, porque eu pensava que fosse uma excelente forma de ser considerado para vagas internacionais. Continuamos na lida!

Comment: Sei como é. Não seria ético te direcionar à sites concorrentes, mas o que posso te dizer é: Procure por sites populares em inglês... A quantidade de ofertas para mim sempre foi proporcional ao tamanho do site (infelizmente a qualidade das ofertas costuma ser inversamente proporcional :D).

Answer (score 3):

Minha experiência pessoal é que, mesmo tendo várias ofertas para trabalho remoto, quase nunca estas vagas aceitam candidatos de locais geograficamente muito afastados ou que não tenham condição imediata de se mudar ao menos para perto do 'local de trabalho' - exceções sendo uma necessidade ou um profissional exceptionais.

Muitas vagas classificadas como *remote* nos Estados Unidos usam um regime parcial - X dias em casa, Y dias no escritório, ou pelo menos a possibilidade de estar lá no dia seguinte. É muito difícil excluir completamente o fator físico da relação de trabalho.

Comment: Marissa Mayer que o diga. :)